# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'.'

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

If I run the code:

```
    object myObject = "abc";
    JToken jToken = (JToken)myObject;
```

it compiles fine, but it throws the cryptic exception the title. It is cryptic since it is possible to cast form String to JToken as withnessed by the following compiling and running correctly:

```
    String mystring = "abc";
    JToken jToken2 = (JToken)mystring;
```

So I am very curious why this is happening?

Of course the above example is a bit silly, but maybe to get a sense of why I am asking this is because the same error is also generated in the following situation.

```
class Program
    public static JToken apply_function(Delegate function, object[] arglist)
    {
        return (JToken)function.DynamicInvoke(arglist);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<string> hello = () => { return "hello world!"; };
        Console.WriteLine(apply_function(hello, new object[0]));
    }
}
```

Where in the actual situation where in want to use `apply_function`, is a situation where I do not have control over the return type, or the argument types of the Delegate supplied to `apply_function`. The only guarantee I have is that the Delegate will be a function that returns something that is castable to JToken.

Comment: Do not put multiple things into one line. A return, cast and function call are 3 things, each of the able to give you compile errors. The only price for squeezing code into one line, is having a hell of a time debugging it. Split the code over multiple lines, using temporary/local variables. Do not worry about performance - outside of debug builds various optimsiations cut underused variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a cast, it's a [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators). You can see [in the docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Implicit_29.htm) that Json.NET defines a conversion from `string` to `JToken`.

The static type in your example is `object` - there's no conversion defined from `object` to `JToken`.

It looks to me from the docs that you should try using [`JToken.FromObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm).

Comment: The JToken.FromObject indeed solves my problem. What still puzzles me is why the error messages shows the dynamic type, when the problem is with the static type. And furthermore, why does it not generate a compiler error if there is a problem with the static type.

Comment: @M.D. The error shows the type `string` because it attempts a cast, not a conversion, which is on the runtime type. You wont get a compilation error because it is possible to cast `object` to `JToken` as long as said object references an instance of `JToken`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this works:

```
string mystring = "abc";
JToken jToken2 = (JToken)mystring;
```

Is that `JToken` has an explicit conversion operator from `string`.

Explicit conversion operators do not respect inheritance hierarchies, as with a standard cast, so that's why it won't work with `object`.

`JToken` has an extensive range of user-defined conversions, but it's not going to work with every type, as it seems like you wan in `apply_function`.

An alternative is [`JToken.FromObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm):

```
public static JToken apply_function(Delegate function, object[] arglist)
{
    return JToken.FromObject(function.DynamicInvoke(arglist));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer of [Charles Mager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320845/charles-mager) made me realize that the static type is the problem and hence that:

```
    public static JToken apply_function(Delegate function, object[] arglist)
    {
        return (dynamic)function.DynamicInvoke(arglist);
    }
```

will also solve the problem. I guess that if one want apply_function to return a `JToken` the `JToken.FromObject` is the better function to use. But not every class might have a static `FromObject` function.

Comment: No, don't use `dynamic`, that will just defer errors to runtime. Not every class needs a `FromObject` method; that is defined on `JToken`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay it was already a runtime error. P.s. have you actually tried to run it with the extra cast to dynamic? Because for me it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Yes it works for this specific example, because there's a conversion from `string`, but try this: `Func<List<string>> hello = () => { return new List<string> { "hello world!" }; };`. It compiles fine, but runtime exception. With `JToken.FromObject`, there is no exception.

Comment: By using `dynamic`, `apply_function` will only work for the types that have defined conversions to `JToken`, other types will give you an exception.

Comment: Yes I realize that my answer only works for types which have defined conversions. That is why I say that the `FromObject` is the best solution for JToken. But what if someone (possibly me) wants to have a `public static TypeWithoutFromObject apply_function(...)` function, then one has no choice but to use conversion and the dynamic keyword solves this.

Comment: In that case I would try to make the method generic; `dynamic` really should be the last resort as you bypass compiler safety.